# Unable to access file in relative path in Scala for test resource

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I have setup my SCALA project using Maven, now I am writing test and need to access a file under sub directory of resource path is like:

```
src/test/resource/abc/123.sql
```

Now I am doing following:

```
val relativepath = "/setup/setup/script/test.sql"
val path = getClass.getResource(relativepath).getPath
println(path)
```

but this is pointing to src/main/resource folder instead of test resource, anyone has the idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does the `path` printout give?

Comment: No idea, but somehow this code works fine as well now :), have been trying different things

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like in Java, it is a good practice to put your resource files under `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`, as Scala provides a nice API from retrieving resource files.

Considering you put your `test.sql` file under `src/test/resources/setup/setup/script/test.sql`, you can easily read the file by doing the following:

**Scala 2.12**

```
import scala.io.Source
val relativePath = "setup/setup/script/test.sql"
val sqlFile : Iterator[String] = Source.fromResource(relativePath).getLines
```

**Prior Scala versions**

```
import scala.io.Source
val relativePath = "setup/setup/script/test.sql"
val stream : InputStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream(relativePath)
val sqlFile : Iterator[String] = Source.fromInputStream(stream).getLines
```

Doing so, you can even have the same file put under the same relative path in `src/main/resources`. When trying to access the resource file in a test, the file from the `src/test/resources` will be considered.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I am getting success with src/main/resources/test.txt, but as soon as I remove /src/main/resources I get exception for file not found

Comment: Could you paste here the structure of your current resource files, in this case? Not sure if I understand this correctly, but if you don't have a `src/main/resources.../` and you try to access a file that resides in `src/test/resources` from a class that is part of `src/main/scala`, it will not work. Also, it is not a good practice to do this. The test resource files should be used only within tests and are meant to define extra properties or override the main resource files for testing purposes, but not the other way around.